# Is it possible to put strings in the copy buffer?

Tags: python, copy, copy-paste

Preferentially using the standard libraries.

Comment: What is "the copy buffer"? What command-line interpretor / text editor / IDE on what operating system?

Comment: @John, OP probably means the clipboard.

Comment: @brainjam: What is "the clipboard"?. The OP needs to tells us exactly what he means. Otherwise we'll end up answering all probable/possible/imagined scenarios.

Comment: @John, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_(software).  I agree that OP can be more explicit, but the tags (python, copy-paste) give a hint as well.

Comment: @brainjam: I am well aware what "**a** clipboard" means. Which particular clipboard does "**the** clipboard refer to? Python tag is because the OP wants Python code to stuff things in "the clipboard". "copy-paste" is a generic activity undertaken in connection with clipboards -- very little hint there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try googling "Python clipboard".  There seem to be various solutions out there.  [Here's one called Pyperclip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) that claims to work across Windows/Mac/Linux